# Large point data,not visible/queryable on zoom in

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, zoom

Using ArcMap. I have around 15 million points layer that I can only see them when I click on 'Zoom to layer'.

When I zoom in the points disappear, I cannot even get info of these (existing) points drawing a rectangle ('select by polygon' gives 0 records).
I have no min/max 'visible scale range' setup.

I am wondering if is a performance problem, but the software does not get frozen on zooming in, and the drawing icon looks fine, but non-active.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the format of the data and what steps you have taken to build a spatial index. It would be expected that a very large layer would take a long time to render, which is why efforts are made to *not* render them until renderable.

Comment: Are your point "simple point" or are they multipoint ? (also, while unlikely for point, geometry error may cause display issue, so running the check geometry or repair geometry tool could be tryed)

Comment: Select by polygon never works well if the layer does not render. Draw a polygon feature and use select by location to get the records not rendering. The globe icon is not always useful; I would look up how to use Windows Task Manager to monitor input/output activities, and to set the Arcmap.exe to high priority.

Comment: How are you storing this data? Shapefile, File GeoDatabase, CSV?